# C# Rotativa ActionAsPDF no parameters passed

Tags: c#, asp.net, rotativa

I'm trying to send parameters with ActionAsPdf using the Rotativa Library (1.6.4), unfortunately, the function is called but the parameter `trainee` in it is always null. 
Here's my code:

```
List<T_Trainee> trainee= new List<T_Trainee>();
foreach (int f in foo)
{
    T_Trainee t = new T_Trainee();
    t.email = (string)Session["Mail"];
    t.phone = (string)Session["Phone"];
    trainee.Add(t);
}

//code to get the PDF     
ActionAsPdf pdf = new ActionAsPdf("Index", trainee) { FileName = "Bulletin.pdf" };
```

Trainee var is a list of object T_Trainee not null -> seen in debug:

```
//function that return the PDF
public ActionResult Index(List<T_Trainee> trainee)
{
    ViewModelFoo vmc = new ViewModelFoo();
    vmc.trainee = trainee;
    return View(vmc);
}
```

When the function is call in debug mode, I can clearly see that the parameter "trainee" is null but I still don't understand why.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

ActionAsPdf seems to be a deprecated function in the last version of Rotativa.

I changed it by ViewAsPdf and now it works. The difference between the two  function is that you have to send directly the view model inside the Index method call with ViewAsPdf.

Here's my code, I hope that it will help someone :

Code to call the index and send the viewModel

```
ViewModelFoo vmc = new ViewModelFoo();
List<T_Trainee> trainees= new List<T_Trainee>();
foreach (int f in foo)
{
    T_Trainee t = new T_Trainee();
    t.email = (string)Session["Mail"];
    t.phone = (string)Session["Phone"];
    trainees.Add(t);
}
vmc.trainees = trainees;
//code to get the PDF     
ViewAsPdf pdf = new ViewAsPdf("Index", vmc)
{
   FileName = "File.pdf",
   PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
   PageMargins = { Left = 0, Right = 0 }
};
```

Index that generate the view

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(vmc);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Only thing I changed was the method signature for Index method. I added the model ViewModelFoo object. public ActionResult Index(ViewModelFoo vmc)

Answer (score 0):

Is foo populated?

Try sample code...

List trainee= new List();
trainee.Add(new T_Trainee {email = "sample@email.com", phone = "555-1212"});

Does that work?

You can also try to bind Action to a model

public ActionResult Index(ViewModelFoo vmc)

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `ActionAsPdf()` is type of `RouteValueDictionary`, which is a dictionary of key and value. You passed in a custom type thereby it converts it to null. It should work if you pass a `RouteValueDictionary` instead.

`ViewAsPdf()` receives an object parameter and treats it as a model for view binding that's why it works.

You can have a look at its source code here:
https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa/blob/master/Rotativa/ActionAsPdf.cs